# Discrepancy with Employment Date in background check

Tags: job-search, background-check, onboarding

I recently got a job offer and I'm in the process of background check.

One previous employment is entered as Jan 1st 2015 to Jan 1st 2015 which is obviously an error or typo from my side or a system error since I don't remember entering those dates in the background check form. My actual dates are from Sep 2015 to December 2015 and I have the same on my resume which I used to apply for the job.

The vendor company which is doing my background check has flagged this as discrepancy after verifying with my previous employer who also gave them the dates Sep 2015 to Dec 2015. Now this Jan 1st 2015 to Jan 1st 2015 which is obviously an error has caused a discrepancy and my background check decision has been made decisional.

Can anyone help me calm down and let me know what could potentially happen, and what steps could I take to clarify this?

Comment: What do you mean by "made decisional"? Did they reject you application?

Comment: Decisional means the employer will need to review the report provided by the background check company and make the decision. The background check company neither passed it or failed it. So the decision is really up to the employer.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone help me calm down and let me know what could potentially happen, and what steps could I take to clarify this?

Chill, Zee. The calmer you are the better one can think and come with a solution :).

*You say that the resume you sent/applied with has the correct dates. I suggest you reach out to the company you are applying and point this out to them.*

Explain that the correct dates are specified in your resume, and that those match with what your past employer said. Ask if there is anything else you can do to help clarify this situation and move forward.

Besides from that, assuming worst case (hopefully not), I suggest you keep your options open and *keep applying and job-hunting*, so you don't depend solely on this possibility.